# Optimisation of subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a relation between users and groups. Users can be in a group or not.

**EDIT** : Added some stuff to the model to make it more convenient.

[image]

Let's say I have a rule to add users in a group considering it has a specific town, and a custom metadata like age 18).

Curently, I do that to know which users I have to add in the group of the people living in Paris who are 18:

```
        SELECT user.id AS 'id'
        FROM user
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT user_id 
            FROM user_has_role_group 
            WHERE role_group_id = 1 -- Group for Paris
        )
        AS T1
        ON user.id = T1.user_id
        WHERE 
        (
        user.town = 'Paris' AND JSON_EXTRACT('custom_metadata', '$.age') = 18
        )
        AND T1.user_id IS NULL
```

It works & gives me the IDs of the users to insert in group.

But when I have 50 groups to proceed, like for 50 town or various ages, it forces me to do 50 requests, it's very slow and not efficient for my Database.

How could I generate a result for each group ?

Something like :

```
role_group_id          user_to_add
1                 1
1                 2
2                 1
2                 3
```

The only way I know to do that for now is to do an UNION on several sub queries like the one above, but of course it's very slow.

Note that the custom_metadata field is a user defined field. I can't create specific columns or tables.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Note that group is a reserved word, making it a poor choice for table/column identifiers - even in arbitrary examples.

Comment: How on earth did you manage to create `user_has_group` rows where the `group_id` is set but the `user_id` is not set ????

Comment: I am also struggling to understand what use a `Group` table is with just an `id` in it and no other indication of what the group is like a `name`

Comment: I'm struggling too. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RiggsFolly If i could comment on a deleted answer, I would say that the one thing we do know is that a SELECT is not required.

Comment: @Strawberry Yea, I went off half cocked so to speak, but while looking to see if my first thought answer was worth posting I came up with lots of questions and thought I would delete it before I got railed on

Comment: I've corrected the model to make it more convenient, but it's not the real one, I thought it was simplier to delete all the irrelevant fields.

Comment: `role_group_id=1` means `town='Paris'`. How do you want to match other groups? `role_group_id=2` means `town=???` Unless you describe this rule it is not possible to make it in one statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I good understood you:

```
select user.id, grp.id
from user, role_group grp
where  (user.id, grp.id) not in (select user_id, role_group_id from user_has_role_group) and user.town in ('Paris', 'Warsav')
```

that code give list of users and group which they not belong from one of towns..

Comment: Actually, I think this could work ! With some tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

To add the missing entries to user_has_role_group, you might want to have some mapping between those town names and their group_id's.

The example below is just using a subquery with unions for that.
But you could replace that with a select from a table.
Maybe even from role_group, if those names correlate with the user town names.

```
insert into user_has_role_group (user_id, group_id)
select u.user_id, g.group_id
from user u
join (
  select 'Paris' as name, 1 as group_id union all
  select 'Rome', 2
  -- add more towns here
) g on (u.town = g.name)
left join user_has_role_group ug 
  on (ug.user_id = u.user_id and ug.role_group_id = g.group_id)
where u.town in ('Paris','Rome') -- add more towns here
  and json_extract(u.custom_metadata, '$.age') = 18
  and ug.id is null;
```